# Access input in GraphQL Prisma Directive

Tags: prisma, plumatic-schema, prisma-graphql

I have a use case where in I want to access query parameter/arguments in the directive. Following is the schema.

`user(where: UserWhereUniqueInput!): User @isAuthenticated`

Query that is fired from playground

`user(where:{id: "test001"}){id name}`

Directive code

`isAuthenticated: async (next, source, args, ctx) => {
let user = ctx.prisma.context.user(where: {})// Need to fetch the user with given id
}`

How can I fetch the user with given id in directives code. I did not get id in `args` variable. Is there a way to get `UserWhereUniqueInput` value in directive?

Comment: I don't think you have access to args in Directives.

Comment: Btw, have a look at this issue, they are trying to implement sa same functionality. https://github.com/LawJolla/prisma-auth0-example/issues/8